# get reference of jquery ui object in touchend

Tags: ipad, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch to map the touch events. jQuery UI droppable has the below code in which the event and ui objects are passed automatically. I want to write a custom handler to which I can pass the same objects. Could any one suggest how I can get the reference of ui object on touchend event on IPAD ? So that I can use same drop function for both desktop and IPAD.

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
        dropFunction(event, ui);
    }
```

so on touchend event I can call dropFunction(event,ui)

Additional info:

I am trying to achieve drag and drop from table row to a jstree. If I just use Touch Punch without modification I am able to do the drag and drop is also being called. As I am reading the values using the below code, it works on desktop browser but not on IPAD.

```
var newOrgId = $('#ohTreeDiv .jstree-hovered').find('span:last').text()
```

the jstree-hovered class is added automatically to the hovered node when using desktop browser however this does not get added on Ipad, so I am adding this class manually in touchend method. After this step I even get the hovered class added. When touchend happens it looks like the drop is not being called.

After dragging the element on the target node of the jstree I have to tap it so that the drop is triggered. @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question: Touch Punch translates touch events into mouse events, and `touchend` will be translated into the appropriate events so `drop` is triggered. You should not have to add anything for that to work. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sometimes when we spell out the issue clearly the solution strikes to us. Thank you Frederic for shaking me a little bit !! Got it working now. I am updating the solution for my issue. @FrédéricHamidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the touchend code which I had to modify little bit to make it working with jstree so that I can read the values with jstree-hovered class. One tip I want to add is when testing remove all the alerts as it will intefere with the values we read using jQuery.

```
    c._touchEnd = function(f) {

    var i = f.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
    var elementFromPoint1 = document.elementFromPoint(i.clientX, i.clientY);
    var id=elementFromPoint1.id;
    var str=new String(id);
    var pos=str.indexOf("dropTarget");
    if(pos>=0){
        elementFromPoint1.className="jstree-hovered";
        }
    if (!a) {
        return;
    }
    d(f, "mouseup");
    d(f, "mouseout");
    if (!this._touchMoved) {
        d(f, "click");
    }
    a = false;
};
```